# unable to connect to aurora mysql from docker container but works using command line

Tags: docker, go, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

am trying to do this from an ec2 instance, trying to connect to aws rds aurora mysql. The following command lets me connect to the  rds:
mysql -h cluster.cluster-c3dpvouhxmjg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port 3306 -u root -p

I have written a golang application and containerized it using docker here:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM artifactory.cloud.com/research/golang:1.10-alpine3.7

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/perfGo/
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/perfGo
COPY ./ $WORKDIR
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN go build

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
RUN ls
RUN chmod +x ./perfGo
EXPOSE 3306
#I set the proxies here

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./perfGo
```

perf.go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
 _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:fdsffdsfs@tcp(cluster.cluster-c3dpvouhxmjg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306)/testdb")
    checkErr(err)
    _,dbErr := db.Exec("USE testdb")
    if err != nil {
        panic(dbErr)
    }

    // insert
    _, inErr := db.Query("INSERT INTO books VALUES('tttt','dsfdsfs','fdsfasaf','55')")

    defer db.Close()
    // if there is an error inserting, handle it
    if inErr != nil {
        panic(inErr.Error())
    }

}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The command I use to run the contianer is

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 -ti 23b3c5c510b4
```

The error I see is :
panic: dial tcp: lookup cluster.cluster-c3dpvouhxmjg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com on 8.8.4.4:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:52640->8.8.4.4:53: i/o timeout
Can someone pls help me out on this. This totally works on container on my mac using mysql on localhost

Comment: That's a DNS error and domain cannot be resolved to IP address.

Comment: @Xaqron is that a proxy issue? or do I need to append http://

Comment: Probably a proxy issue. Depends on 1) if your proxy resides in AWS and 2) your app forwards DNS queries to the proxy. BTW that domain resolves to a private IP which is valid only inside AWS network but you are using Google DNS server to resolve it and it fails.